# Why AEM as war file?

Tags: jar, war, aem

Adobe Experience Manager is downloadable in two format: either as a standalone jar File(which has Apache Felix as the OSGi Container, CRX as the repository, Apache Sling for content delivery and it's own Servlet Container which i believe is jetty nowadays).
and also as a war file. apart from the application server part, this war file has all the other elements and war is deployed on say WebSphere or Apache Tomcat.

i don't seem to understand what is advantage of having AEM as a .war file when a standalone jar will do the work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some users want to use war files as that's what they are used to in their environments, but you are right that the runnable jar does the job just fine, with a simpler environment.

Answer (score 0):

with a war file, we can deploy it to EJB server like Jboss